# Covariance calculation in a DiD estimation

Tags: mathematical-statistics, estimation, least-squares, covariance, difference-in-difference

I am estimating a difference-in-difference model estimating the effect of a parental leave reform on female wages. It is not possible to take the logarithm of the varaibles as a lot of wages are 0.
I am therefore transforming the varaibles into percentage change by dividing with the average of the control group after treatment.

$$y_{it}=\beta_0+\beta_1\cdot Caug22_i+\beta_2\cdot T_{it}+\sum_{k=21m2}^{23m6} \gamma_k \mathbf{1}(t=k)+u_{it} $$
$$\tilde{\beta}_2=\frac{\hat{\beta}_2}{\hat{\bar{W}}}$$

I then use the delta method to transform the standard errors as the estimate is divided by another estimate.

$$Var(g(X))\approx(\nabla g(x))' Cov(X)\nabla g(X)$$

Where in this case $g(X)=\tilde{\beta}_2$, $\nabla g(X)=\left(\frac{1}{\hat{\bar{W}}},-\frac{\hat{\beta_2}}{\hat{\bar{W}}^2}\right)$ and $X=\left(\hat{\bar{W}},\hat{\beta}_2\right)$.

$$Var(\tilde{\beta}_2)=\frac{1}{\hat{\bar{W}}^2}\cdot Var(\hat{\beta_2})+\frac{\hat{\beta}_2^2}{\hat{\bar{W}}^4}\cdot Var(\hat{\bar{W}})-2\cdot\frac{\hat{\beta}_2}{\hat{\bar{W}}^3}\cdot Cov(\hat{\beta_2},\hat{\bar{W}})$$
$$\Leftrightarrow SE(\tilde{\beta}_2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\cdot\sqrt{\frac{1}{\hat{\bar{W}}^2}\cdot Var(\hat{\beta}_2)+\frac{\hat{\beta}_2^2}{\hat{\bar{W}}^4}\cdot Var(\hat{\bar{W}})-2\cdot\frac{\hat{\beta_2}}{\hat{\bar{W}}^3}\cdot Cov(\hat{\beta}_2,\hat{\bar{W}})}$$

But how do I calculate the covariance between the estimate and the average of the dependent variable? Is the estimate seen as a constant in that setting?